# Blazor handle the error in the response from Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

There are two applications:

1. Blazor server-side
2. Web API (written long ago)

WebApi action

```
public async Task<object> GetAllAsync(...)
{
   ...
   // Какая то проверка
   throw new Exception("Что то пошло не так");
   ...
}
```

An example view of a method in a client application(Blazor server-side)

```
    public async Task GetAllAsync()
    {
            var httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{address}/api/foo");

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // successfully
            }
            else
            {
                // How to get the error message here?
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is: how to properly handle this kind of error from API?

**ps**

```
var exception = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();
```

HttpError pulls a dependency with .NetFramework 4.6 (but initially I use .net core 3 preview)

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?  You can throw with `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HttpContent class does not define a ReadAsAsync method. This is an extension method which I believe is considered obsolete,and is no longer supported. You may use ReadAsStringAsync(), ReadAsStreamAsync(), etc.

Example how to serialize the exception content to string:

```
var exception = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The following code snippet demonstrates how to use HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync() to serialize the HTTP content to a byte array as an asynchronous operation, and then parse the array to a type you may define to hold the http error (something similar to the HttpError object, which you should not use, but simpler).

```
var responseBytes = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```

Note: Change the type specifier **T** to your custom type, or use built-in types such as string, according to your design...

```
JsonSerializer.Parse<T>(responseBytes, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });
```

Hope this helps